# How to user setHideOverlayWindows in Android

Tags: android

I am using [Tapjacking](https://developer.android.com/topic/security/risks/tapjacking)  prevention in my app. Before Android 12 I can block the user and not to enter sensitive data if any overlay exiting over the app. But after Android 13 and 14 it is not working. We setHideOverlayWindows(boolean) for this above Android 12. But there is not proper docs or samples for this. I am not able to understand how it is working.

Before Android 12 I used the following code.

```
boolean badTouch;
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 29){
                    badTouch = ((flags & FLAG_WINDOW_IS_OBSCURED) != 0);

                }else{
                    badTouch = (((flags & FLAG_WINDOW_IS_PARTIALLY_OBSCURED) != 0)
                            || ((flags & FLAG_WINDOW_IS_OBSCURED) != 0));
                }
```

Above Android 12 version I am using the following code.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
                    RootedCheckActivity.this.getWindow().setHideOverlayWindows(true);
                }
```

Enabled HIDE_OVERLAY_WINDOWS permission in Manifest.

But nothing happens. Can anyone explain how to use setHideOverlayWindows and how to check it is working or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RootedCheckActivity.this.getWindow().setHideOverlayWindows(true);` will close the overlay window automatically. If you want to test it in real time run any screen recorder application. After that run your app with `setHideOverlayWindows`. Now you can see that recorder app is hidden when you app in foreground.